# Raspberry Pi FlexRay HAT

Tags: hardware, hat, can-bus

I've been searching for a couple of days for a FlexRay HAT / module for Raspberry pi without success.

Is there such a module available?

Comment: Never heard of FlexRay HAT. CAN HAT is everywhere. For FlexRay, you need to DIY.